# Twentyseventeen theme and Bootstrap are seemingly incompatible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, theme-twenty-seventeen

I'm having an issue with Bootstrap on twentyseventeen theme. I've included Bootstrap, everything is loading, but Bootstrap changed the theme's font size and margins even though it loads before everything so it shouldn't affect other styles. Has anyone encountered this before? I've googled it and come up with ziltch. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, but this is not a real question. questions are at least expected to include relevant code.

Comment: It is a real question, how can it not be, it is an issue I'm having that I need to discuss with the community. I wasn't aware beginners weren't allowed to ask questions that weren't "advanced enough". What code do you want me to post? The enqueuing works fine, does what I tell it to do, but for some reason the css of bootstrap is interfering with theme's css when it is not supposed to. What code would you have me include here? I just want to know whether someone had a similar issue they managed to resolve with a plugin or sth, since I couldn't find any solutions online.

Comment: "does someone else have this bug?" do have a question mark, which makes it a question in most languages, but questions here should be answerable with authority. A yes or no answers are both valid to your question and have zero value. To make it worse you ask about bootstrap which is not part of wordpress and therefor off topic here

Comment: I've asked if someone had "any ideas", which does mean "any ideas as to how to solve this", and it does have to do with wordpress because it is wordpress i'm trying to integrate bootstrap into. I'm sorry if this question offended you in some way, but you are free to skip what you do not like.

Comment: WordPress just loads the CSS files like you tell it to. The issues lines inside the CSS files. There are possibly rules/selectors that trigger both the Divi and the Bootstrap CSS. Hence you get the mix up. This would also happen on a static HTML page where you run the Divi and the Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: it is really annoying to try to have a factual discussions with lawyers here in the comments (. being in the context of wordpress is not enough, questions should be wordpress specific, your question is about bootstrap. At the very least questions about integration with 3rd party software should include all the relevant details related to that software.

Comment: If you had been kind enough to try to explain factually why my question doesn't belong here as @lowtechsun did, or tried to help me find a more appropriate place to post, I wouldn't have turned into a "lawyer" as you say, but would have thanked you for your reply. I thought it might be a bug in Wordpress or its enqueueing system or I don't know, I am a beginner as I said, so that's why I posted here in the first place.

Comment: @TangledHeadphones Don't get _entangled_ in such discussion, happened to me too, all it does is makes you loose time that you could use to start reading on the links. With time you will ask better questions, I hope I do, fingers crossed.

Comment: Hahaha, that was a good one @lowtechsun I'm going over to learnwebcode  right now :)

Comment: Styling doesn't work that way, even if it's included first. For example, if your theme styles the header as `h1 {color:white}` and bootstrap styles it as `body h1{color:black}`, bootstrap will override the theme, since its style has a higher priority than theme's.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap classes are not the same classes in WordPress, you need to write Bootstrap HTML markup into your theme file and then it will work. [Here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) look at the examples given and mix the Bootstrap HTML with WordPress template tags and PHP.

Start with [this](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) basic template and replace the parts that you want WordPress to do for you. For that have a look at [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and the Wordpress [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Get to know [template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/) and check out [this fantastic series of small tuts](http://learnwebcode.com/learn-wordpress/) to get you going with the basics. If you go through the first couple of tuts, "adding" Bootstrap to WordPress will be a breeze for ya. But then you might want to create your own theme instead of relying on Bootstrap?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate it :) I've included some static HTML code inside the front-page.php file and its PHP code, and it shows on the front page as it is supposed to, but my font-sizes and margins got reduced for some reason, and are showing too small on the entire website, not just the portion using Bootstrap. But I'll check out the tutorials you've linked, and if i have too I'll correct all these one by one.

As for making my own theme, I'm afraid I'm too much of a beginner with PHP for that.

Comment: That was what I thought too at first until I finished the tuts with perseverance (no talent or Physics PHD needed, just training) and scored a client website with the knowledge within a month after that. Go through it, in 30 days you won't look back and glad you followed through. The course material is up to date and the bit and pieces you need are across here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress). As for the fonts, you possibly have double font definitions declared in the Divi and Bootstrap CSS. Really best to start with your own basic theme before you go further.

Comment: Also, the fonts etc. and other issues are not really WordPress issues, but drive from the fact your mix the Divi with the Bootstrap CSS and possibly have the same selectors with different values that override each other. In your HTML you need to specifically assign the proper classes to the classes given in Bootstrap CSS, otherwise the HTML either won't have any style or use the Divi CSS by chance if for example it uses a universal CSS selector.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know where I could post such questions if they are not appropriate here?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) tagged `CSS` and `HTML` for example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant **TwentySeventeen** CSS, not Divi CSS!